# import all sections of the connected user's profile on LinkedIn using the LinkedIn API

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api

I want to import all sections of the connected user's profile on LinkedIn using the LinkedIn API in Python. I used the REST API to retrieve profile information by sending a GET request to the URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me, using the obtained access_token. However, I want to import the education and experience sections, and I am unsure of what to add to the URL to achieve this. What parameters do I need to add to the URL to retrieve the education and experience sections of the connected user's profile using the LinkedIn API in Python?"

i tried this url
" api_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,headline,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams),educations,experience)' "
but when i execute this url form  : response = oauth.get(api_url)
profile_data = response.json()
the profile_data contain only the name , image profil and emailAdress .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.